# cannot install puphpeteer 2.0.0

Tags: php

Attempting to install puphpeteer with composer fails with the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires nesk/puphpeteer ^2.0 -> satisfiable by nesk/puphpeteer[2.0.0].
    - nesk/puphpeteer 2.0.0 requires psr/log ^1.0 -> found psr/log[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.4] but the package is fixed to 3.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require nesk/puphpeteer:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require nesk/puphpeteer:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

I tried the --with-all-dependencies option but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem was solved here [PuPHPeteer php bridge package unable to install on Laravel 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340505/puphpeteer-php-bridge-package-unable-to-install-on-laravel-9)

Concisely, the nesk/puphpeteer package has been abandoned and workarounds are needed to make it work.